# fetch data error with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I used two classes
I call the second class as below

```
let s = new SearchExtend();

output = s.fetchData(search)
alert(output)
```

The second function:

```
fetchData = (search) => {

      fetch('http://example.com/search.php' , {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({

          // Getting the search.
          search: search
        })
      }).then((response) => response.json())

       .then((responseJson) => {
             return responseJson;
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
}
```

But i get in "alert" undefined

When I use this.setState instead of return, I get the following error:

warning setstate(...) can only update a mounted or mounting component

Comment: let form = new FormData(); s.fetchData(form ) use FormData and pass params and value with append
 form.append("paramname", 'paramvalue')   body:search   no need  JSON.stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` because you are using promises. Initially it returns undefined and once promise is resolved you get the actually data.

A better way to handle this would be to return the promise and resolve it externally as follows:-

```
const fetchApi = () => {
   return fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people" , {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
   .then((responseJson) => {
    return responseJson;
  })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
}


fetchApi()
.then((data) => {
  console.log("data", data);
})
```

Comment: He is getting undefined because he is not returning anything in his `fetchData` method. It has nothing to do with Promises.

Comment: thanks its worked, how can before loading the data print the Text such as loading... or import the class